# How to declare string parameter in sql function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have written a function in SQL  to output the sales figures of Shop based on the shop name.Therefore the parameters for the query is text, but I keep receiving an error when it comes to compiling. Here is my function

```
DELIMTER //
Create Function getShopSaleFigures(shop_name Text ) 
Return Decimal (5,2)
Declare 
BEGIN
DECLARE shop_Sales DECIMAL(5,2);
SELECT shopname, SUM( rentalrate + overduecharge ) into Shop_Sales
FROM frs_Shop
NATURAL JOIN frs_FilmRental
WHERE shopname = shop_name
RETURN Shop_Sales
END //
DELIMITER;
```

Here is the link to an error that I keep receiving. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2BPc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of issues here. first declare `shop_name Text` to be `varchar` like `shop_name varchar(100)`. And you have a empty `declare` statement as pointed below. Remove it.

```
Return Decimal (5,2)
Declare      <--------- This one
BEGIN
```